Difference between variables defined with ascending vs. descending indexes
Does it make a difference if you define indexes in descending or in ascending order at the outset?
Specifically, suppose I have the following items defined in a module:
output [7:0] o_RX_Byte;

reg [7:0] r_RX_Byte = 0;
reg [0:2] r_Bit_Index = 0;

If bit 8 is considered the most significant bit, which bit is being referred to in the statement:
r_RX_Byte[r_Bit_Index] <= i_RX_Serial;

That is, is the most significant bit of r_RX_Byte getting i_RX_Serial or is the least significant bit of r_RX_Byte getting i_RX_Serial?
Would it have made a difference if the the items had been defined instead as:
output [0:7] o_RX_Byte;

reg [0:7] r_RX_Byte = 0;
reg [0:2] r_Bit_Index = 0;


pl check if this is related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/verilog-bit-direction

TL;DR:
[7:0] vs [0:7] does DIFFER.
Long version:
given
wire [7:0] r_RX_Byte = 8'b1000_0000;
The bit[7] of the bus will be asserted. Not all the other bits.
On the other hand, given
wire [0:7] r_RX_Byte = 8'b1000_0000;
The bit[0] of the bus will be asserted. Not all the other bits.
